# Docker context how to use specific ssh key

Tags: docker

I would like to use a docker context to contact a server via ssh. I have a number of different ssh keys on my local. How do I tell a context to use a specific key? I've tried:

```
docker context create test --docker "host=ssh://<username>@<ip-of-server>,key=C:/path/to/key"
```

but no dice, it always asks for a password. Is there a way to tell a docker context what ssh key to use?

Comment: Did you activated created context? `docker context ls` then `docker context use <context-name>`?

Comment: Yup, otherwise it wouldn't have asked for my password when performing commands right? The exampe is `docker --context=test service ls`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The key you are trying to use in the example you provided refers to the TLS key.

Docker is using your local SSH agent. Any keys loaded into your agent will be accessible for the connection:

- if not present already, install a SSH agent;
- generate the SSH key pair;
- add the private key to the SSH agent on the machine from which you want to issue the docker commands;
- add the public key on the target Docker host machine, in the `<username-home>/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- now try a regular SSH into the target Docker host(`ssh <username>@<ip-of-server>`). Accept the fingerprint. If you are not asked for a password, docker won't ask for it either.

Create and activate the docker context, then run a dummy docker command:

```
docker context create test --docker "host=ssh://<username>@<ip-of-server>"
docker context use test
docker ps
```

Comment: That's a little more annoying than just being able to specify a -i attribute to use, but it did work. Thanks!

Comment: To be fair, you can also configure the key (and many other options) in `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (or their Windows equivalents if you're not using Linux): https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/. That will work with Docker CLI, but not with docker-compose or vscode docker plugin (and possibly others), although the developers say they will implement it eventually.

Comment: It didn't work for me >Warning: DOCKER_HOST environment variable overrides the active context. To use "test", either set the global --context flag, or unset DOCKER_HOST environment variable

Comment: That didn't work for me either - I get "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at http://docker.example.com. Is the docker daemon running?" error message when trying to connect over SSH