# Getting 'Host key verification failed' when using ssh in docker context

Tags: docker, ssh

i am setting up docker context [like described here](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-deploy-on-remote-docker-hosts-with-docker-compose/) and cofigured the ssh key and the context. Unfortunately I keep getting an error from docker while i'm in the new context:

```
docker context use myhostcontext
docker ps

error during connect: Get "http://docker.example.com/v1.24/containers/json": command [ssh -l user -- myhost docker system dial-stdio] has exited with exit status 255, please make sure the URL is valid, and Docker 18.09 or later is installed on the remote host: stderr=ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
```

Suprisingly when i ssh into `user@myhost` the connection is established as it should be.
`ssh -vv user@myhost` shows that it uses the given key in ~/.ssh/config

Additional Info:

- Platform: Ubuntu 20.04
- Docker: 20.10.23
- OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

---

Here is what i've done:

I've created a docker context with

```
docker context create myhostcontext --docker "host=ssh://user@myhost"
```

I also created a new ssh keypair with ssh-keygen (tried with rsa and ecdsa),
executed `ssh-add /path/to/key` and `ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/key user@myhost`

I tried with using "id_rsa" as keyname as well as "myhost" to make sure its not just a default naming problem.

Looking at several instructions (e.g. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63868735/docker-context-how-to-use-specific-ssh-key)) unfortunately did not help. I also checked the authorized_keys on the remote host and the public key on my local machine, they match.

My ~/.ssh/config looks like this

```
Host myhost
  HostName myhost
  User user
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myhost
```

Also removing entries from known_host did not help.
Using the remote hosts IP instead of its name did not help either.

Installing ssh-askpass just shows me, that the authenticity could not be established (default message when using ssh on a host for the first time). Since I later want to use docker context in a CI/CD environment i don't want to have any non-cli stuff.

The only other possible "issue" that comes to my mind is that the `user` of the remote host is different that the one i am using on the client. But - if understood correctly - that should not be an issue and also i would not know how to manage that.

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated, since I am struggling with this for days.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I also got this error when I hadn't trusted the fingerprint for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

> Host key verification failed.

I think the problem is caused by `StrictHostKeyChecking` (The prompt asking to accept the **Host's fingerprint** when you ssh into a machine for the **first time**. When the fingerprint is accepted it is added to the `known_host` file permanently and ssh won't ask again).

Since you already added `StrictHostKeyChecking no` to the `~/.ssh/config`
and mentioned sshing into the machine uses the correct key and works as expected, the only cause I can think of is that you run docker commands by another user.
Although if that's not the case, try adding `StrictHostKeyChecking no` to the global ssh config located at `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `/etc/ssh_config` temporaly and see if it solves it.

One other thing you could try is adding the key to **ssh-agent**. Like this:

```bash
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" && ssh-add ~/.ssh/myhost
```

then try `docker ps` with the remote context.

> Installing ssh-askpass just shows me, that the authenticity could not be established (default message when using ssh on a host for the first time).

If the ssh key does not have a passphrase, ssh-askpass has no use here.

> Since I later want to use docker context in a CI/CD environment i don't want to have any non-cli stuff.

Not sure if it's the correct way but this is my **gitlab-ci** job that uses docker context:

```yaml
deploy_to_docker:
  image: docker:20.10.21
  script:
    - unset DOCKER_HOST # DOCKER_HOST variable could overwrites docker context, so unsetting it
    - chmod 400 $SSH_KEY_FILE # Set the right permission for the key file
    - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" # Running ssh-agent
    - ssh-add $SSH_KEY_FILE # Adding the key to the agent
    - echo "CHECKING IF KEY WAS ADDED" && ssh-add -l # Checking key was added correctly
    - echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> $(find /etc -iname ssh_config) # Avoiding host check by changing the global configuration of ssh client
    - docker context create remote --docker "host=ssh://$SSH_USER_IP" # Creating the new ssh context
    - docker context use remote # Using the remote created context
    - docker info
    - docker ps -a
```

**SSH_KEY_FILE** is a CI/CD variable file and contains the ssh private key. **(WITH A NEW LINE IN THE END)**

**SSH_USER_IP** is a CI/CD variable and contains the string `user@myhost:port`